# compact set has a countable base

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a compact set. Then, there exists a countable set $S \subseteq K $ such that $\overline{S} =  K$

My try:

Notice for any $n$, the collection $U_n = \{ B( x, \frac{1}{n} ) : x \in  K \}$ covers $K$ since

$$ K = \bigcup_{x \in X } U_n $$

By compactness, we can select $x_1,...,x_n$ such that

$$ K = \bigcup_{i=1}^n B(x_i , \frac{1}{i} ) $$

Let $F_n = \{ x_1,...,x_n \} $. MY approach would be to put $S = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} F_n $. Since $S$ is union of finite sets, then $S$ must be countable.

I am still struggling trying to show $S$ is dense in $K$. IS my approach correct so far?

Any help would be really appreciated.

thanks.

Comment: Do you really think the Cantor set is a closure of a countable set?

Comment: @EricTowers: Did you really mean to suggest that the Cantor set is **not** the closure of a countable set???

Comment: @bof:  It's the right potential counterexample to have in mind for this type of problem.  It's uncountable and each point is a limit point, so potentially trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues with indices. If the collection $U_n$ has index $n$, the finite set will have, say, $k_n$ elements (not $n$ as you wrote). Moreover the balls centered in $x_i$ have radius $1/n$. And such points should be denoted with two indexes: $x_{n,i}$, $n\in \mathbb N$, $i=1,\dots,k_n$.

This being said the proof is there. Given any $x\in K$ you want to find a sequence in $S$ converging to $x$. For every $n$ there exists $x_{n,i_n}$ such that $d(x_{n,i_n},x) < 1/n$. Hence that is the sequence which converges to $x$.